# Provide one file where all error messages are defined in c++

Tags: strings, error-handling, c++17

I would like to store all error messages in one file and call them for example with

```
if (!std::filesystem::exists(ArgFilename)) {
        throw std::runtime_error{error_001_nofile};
    } else {
//do something
}
```

The file `errorcodes.h` is included to the main program and looks like

```
#ifndef SRC_ERRORCODES_H_
#define SRC_ERRORCODES_H_
#include <string_view>

constexpr char error_001_nofile[] = "Error 001: File not found.";
constexpr char error_002_nomem[] = "Error 002: Not enough memory.";
#endif /* SRC_ERRORCODES_H_ */
```

[Cevelop](https://cevelop.com/) warns, that `constexpr char` is no proper `c++`, but `c` code. Is there a clean `c++` solution to manage error messages?

[image: Cevelop warns, that constexpr char is no proper c++, but c code.]

Comment: `const` should be enough if there's nothing to evaluate.

Comment: Why did someone down vote? What can I improve in the question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you. Will change that here, but I leave the question as is for the reader.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using C-string constants in C++. I would write `char const* name = "value";`, but I think in the end it's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr` is probably overkill, but not in any way wrong.

You might consider using the C++ universal style initializisation:

```c++
constexpr char error_001_nofile[]{"Error 001: File not found."};
```

or using a `std::string`:

```c++
constexpr std::string error_001_nofile{"Error 001: File not found."};
```